# Getting error while accessing hiddenfield's value set using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, hidden-field

i have a hidden field. and its value is set using JavaScript,for this my code is:-`

```
    function Selected(obj, id) {
          var hdd = $('[id$=hdd_jobid]')
        $("#tableOne tr").removeClass("selected");
        $("#tableOne tr").addClass("even");
        if (obj.className != 'selected') {
            obj.className = 'selected';
            hdd.val= id;
            alert(hdd.val);
        }
        else {
            obj.className = 'prev_class';

        }
    }
</script>`
```

its working but when i m accessing hidden field's value at server side its coming null.. I don't know what i have to do..  please help

Comment: hdd is a jquery object not an element so `hdd.value` wont work. It will be either `hdd.val()` or `hdd.get(0).value`.

Comment: there was a mistake in previous comment, updated.

Comment: `hdd[0].value = id` **or** `hdd.val(id)` (notice the parentheses). If that's not working, include the relevant generated HTML code, from where you're calling Selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value won't work, should be: `hdd.val(id); alert(hdd.val());`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `hdd.value = id` use `hdd.val('id')` since you have a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.Form[hidData] or hiddata.Value
```

at server side retrive the hidden field value